# How to find out which js code changes selected index

Tags: javascript, firebug, dropdown, inspection

I have a dropdown and my selected index is set by php (which works as long as javascript is disabled).

When i enable javascript, then my selected index is changed to the first option as soon as the page is loaded. Now i need to find out which piece of js changes my selected index.

Can anyone tell me please how to find this out, for example by using firebug?

Comment: a demo on jsfiddle could be good

Comment: https://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/3265

Just take a look at the first dropdown.

Comment: sorry i didn't get nothing from your link, plz make a code in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5cf1jnhq/

Something changes my selected option, just like the js code there.
On my website there is quite a lot of js, and i need to find out which piece of code is responsible for that.

Comment: what is the problem on this fiddle ?

Comment: The problem is that on my homepage javascript code changes the selected value of the dropdown.
I need to find out which js code is doing this.

Comment: Well in your fiddle this code `jQuery('select').val('5');` change your vaule to the value 5

Comment: Forget about the fiddle and take a look here:
https://www.austrokamin.at/catalog/product/view/id/3265

It's the first dropdown ("Ausführung").
The selected option should be "DW Premium 1,0 mm"

There must be javascript code which changes the selected option from "DW Premium 1,0 mm"  to "Bitte treffen Sie eine Auswahl...."

I want to find out which piece of code does this.